# Edit Existing pdf file using codeigniter and email to this editing pdf file

Tags: database, codeigniter, pdf

I have a pdf file which look like [This is my pdf file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3yAD.jpg)

Firstly i want to put database value value in this pdf blank option using codeigniter. 
 Secondly  i want to email to this editing pdf file . one is for user and another is for admin.

Please give me full direction because i am beginner for Codeigniter.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor English.

Thirdly its automatically download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think you can't edit pdf but I suggest a solution to you make a template for your pdf as view and pass the values you want to the view by using

```
$this->load->view("viewname",$data,TRUE);
```

The third paramter is to return html as string then use a library to convert this string of html to pdf I suggest two libraries **tcpdf** It is popular pdf library but personally I didn't use it, or [Snappy](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy) I use it personally but installation of it is little bit difficult but I recommend to use it you can install via composer 
you can Intgrate composer in codeigniter by using the following tutorial
[Composer Integration](https://philsturgeon.uk/php/2012/05/07/composer-with-codeigniter/)

I hope my answer would be useful

Comment: but i know that pdf file rewrite using codeigniter. i see some related solution . but i can't get full documentation . Thanks

Comment: I don't think that pdf allows editing option think of normal pdf file is there any program that can edit text of pdf, there is some softwares that add pages or remove pages, but I dont think that there is a solution to edit pdf even in desktop applications